# Basic "for loop" in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

i have a basic problem about for loop for R. But i can't understand. it's my code.

```
i<-0
z<-numeric(6)
for(i in 1:5){
i<-i+1
z[i]<-i
}
```

i want the output to be

```
>z
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

but it generated

```
>z
[1] 0 2 3 4 5 6
```

why?

Comment: You have a vector of length 6.  So, why is it `1:5` in `for` loop?  Perhaps `for(i in 1:6){z[i] <- i}`

Comment: i think i=6, i+1 will exceed 6.

Comment: For this specific problem, you don't need `i+1`. just do `z[i] <- i`

Comment: BTW you don't need a loop `z <- 1:6` (probably you know that, just in case)

Comment: @Keven R is not a zero indexed language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop sets the following values, broken down by iteration:

1. `i<-1`
    `i<-2`
    `z[2]<-2`
2. `i<-2`
    `i <-3`
    `z[3]<-3`
3. ...
4. ...
5. `i<-5`
    `i<-6`
    `z[6]<-6`

As you can see, `z[1]` is never set because you increment `i` before using it as an index. Change the loop to just do `z[i]<-i` and nothing else. Also, set the loop to run from `1` to `6` instead of to `5` if you want to set `6` elements:

```
z<-numeric(6)
for(i in 1:6){
z[i]<-i
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer but it is probably worth pointing out that the whole approach is nuts; in R you should do z <- 1:6 and be done with it.  It's just possible @Kevin really needs to be told that, not how to fix his loop.

Comment: I figured the OP was having problem with the logic of programming in the first place. It seems that R being the language of choice is purely incidental. Of course my impression may be colored by the fact that I don't know any R myself...