# How to perform a for-loop for a variable in data.fame?

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I am learning the `for loop` in `R`. I am trying to figure it out how to make a `for loop` in an specific `variable` in `data.frame`. I looked into several example in stackoverflow such as [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675419/basic-for-loop-in-r), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167964/how-to-create-a-for-loop-in-r), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162363/how-to-start-a-for-loop-in-r-programming) but none is useful of what I am looking for!

As an example using the `mtcars` dataset , let say I want to perform a `for loop` to:

look into the `cyl` and define for `cyl 4,6,8,` write and substitute with `strings` (`low, medium, high`), respectively.

```
for (i in mtcars$cyl) {
  if (mtcars$cyl == 4){ 
    print("low")} 
  if (mtcars$cyl == 6) {
    print ("medium")}
  if (mtcars$cyl == 8) {
    print ("high")}
    }
```

Certainly this is not the case!

**what expected is something like this:**

```
                  mpg   cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

**convert to:**

```
                   mpg   cyl       disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   medium    160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   medium    160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   low       108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   medium    258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   high      360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   medium    225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Any help with **explanation** is highly appreciated!

Comment: No need for loops: `mtcars$newcol <- factor(mtcars$cyl, labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))` See `?factor` for details.

Comment: So its generally preferred to avoid loops wherever possible in R. This is why Franks response and the first part of D.B.'s answer are really the more correct solutions. Rather than spending time with loops, which are slower and end up being much more complicated, consider spending time learning array function and becoming comfortable with the 'apply' group of functions. They are FAR superior when it comes to neatness and readability of code, as well as the speed with which they may perform a given operation.

Comment: @AronBoettcher thanks a lot for the constructive advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular operation would be possible without loop.

```
df = mtcars
df$cyl[df$cyl == 4] = "low" #Subset the cyl values equal to 4 and assign 'low'
#Repeat for other values
```

But for running loop, I would go about like this

```
df = mtcars

for (i in 1:length(df$cyl)) { #Iterate over the length of df$cyl
#You could also do "for (i in seq_along(df$cyl)"
#Run "seq_along(df$cyl)" and "1:length(df$cyl)" to understand what values are being generated
    if (df$cyl[i] == 4){ #Index df$cyl by [i]. If the ith value is 4, assign 'low'
        df$cyl[i] = "low"
    }
    if (df$cyl[i] == 6) {
        df$cyl[i] = "medium"
    }
    if (df$cyl[i] == 8) {
        df$cyl[i] = "high"
    }
}
```

Comment: A small thing: when helping beginners, try to encourage patterns like `for (i in seq_along(df$cyl)` rather than `for (i in 1:length(df$cyl))`.